# Show modal and wait for action for each element while looping

Tags: javascript, for-loop, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm looking for simple solution for a loop where I have to confirm each element. I was looking at pausing and resuming, but it's quite a hassle. Is there any other way to make it easy? I'm sure that this problem is not so rare and many people have stuck upon it.

What I want to achieve is this - I'm looping through the list and if I don't find item by its EAN code then it opens search function to find this and after the item is found (or not) user clicks `Next` and resume with looping until same situation occurs.

Some code that I have for now:

```
for(var f = 0; f < biLen; f++){

                var ean_parsed = parsedList[i][1];              
                if(beerList[f].get("ean") === ean_parsed){
                    console.log("Beer found: " + beerList[f].get("beer_name"));
                    break;
                } else {
                    if(f === biLen - 1){
                        //open modal, search for item and then continue looping    
                        console.log("B'r not found: " + parsedList[i][0]);                  
                    }                   
                }
            }
```

edit (whole function code instead of piece of it):

```
function parserCompareList(){                   

        var parsedList = parseResult;
        var piLen = parsedList.length;
        var beerList = listaPiwArr;
        var biLen = beerList.length;

        var new_offer = [];
        var counter = document.getElementById('imHeader');

        for(var i = 0; i < piLen; i++){
                    counter.innerHTML = i + "/" + piLen; //plain text that's keeping where we actually are with this
            for(var f = 0; f < biLen; f++){

                var ean_parsed = parsedList[i][1];              
                if(beerList[f].get("ean") === ean_parsed){

                    console.log("Beer found: " + beerList[f].get("beer_name"));
                    break;
                } else {
                    if(f === biLen - 1){
                        console.log("B'r not found: " + parsedList[i][0]);

                    }                   
                }
            }

    }

}
```

### ANSWER:

```
var indexCache;

function loop() {
    var index = indexCache || 0;

    for (var f = index; f < biLen; f++) {
        var ean_parsed = parsedList[i][1];
        if (beerList[f].get("ean") === ean_parsed) {
            console.log("Beer found: " + beerList[f].get("beer_name"));
            break;
        } else {
            if (f === biLen - 1) {
                // Assuming $modal is the bootstrap modal
                indexCache = f;

                //$modal.modal().one('hide.bs.modal', loop);
                $('#importModal').modal('show').one('hidden.bs.modal', loop) //  <-- this one works like a charm
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

loop();
```

Comment: please further explain, this description is so vague.

Comment: @Siddharth edited - is that enough? I don't know which details could help

Comment: you are talking about `modal` and `twitter-bootstrap` , what is that context?

Comment: @Siddharth I need them to be show on each step of the loop - I'm no pro coder so just-in-case I wanted to mention that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var indexCache;

function loop() {
    var index = indexCache || 0;

    for (var f = index; f < biLen; f++) {
        var ean_parsed = parsedList[i][1];
        if (beerList[f].get("ean") === ean_parsed) {
            console.log("Beer found: " + beerList[f].get("beer_name"));
            break;
        } else {
            if (f === biLen - 1) {
                // Assuming $modal is the bootstrap modal
                indexCache = f;

                $modal.modal().one('hide.bs.modal', loop);

                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

loop();
```

We have an indexCache variable that holds the index of the beer that is being handled.

If EAN is found, great! we handle it and move on to the next beer.

If not, we store the current beer index in the cache and show the modal and quit the loop immediately. When the modal is hidden, the loop resumes from the cached index.

PS. I am assuming you are using Twitter Bootstrap modal. And therefore, adding a handler to the event 'hide.bs.modal'. But similar thing could be done with your own modal implementation if that is the case.

Comment: Looks nice! I've updated my question since in Your solution there is `return` statement which exits all the loops. I think we're very close to make it happen :)

Comment: Good solution, it may be worth pointing out the flaw in the OP's question. That is, unless you use a native confirm dialog, there is no way to gather input in a synchronous loop and you have to asynchronous code as you have shown

Comment: @JuanMendes first time I hear of synchronous loops. And yes, it's sort of a confirm dialog.

Comment: OP is using Bootstrap modal since he has tagged this question with Twitter Bootstrap. Loop has to be async then.

Comment: @PrashantPalikhe I have strange problem: after each `hide` on modal the longer I wait with confirming the more logs I see in between so I suppose it's still looping. Could You check if I made any error? https://gist.github.com/janswist/72b3917399e515c79c89

Comment: Line 38: Use .one() instead of .on(), otherwise you keep binding more and more event handlers for when the modal is hidden.

Comment: @PrashantPalikhe ok, now it works only for one repetion - i.e. after first time it gone to modal it fires loop once more and that's it. Modal is not shown again. Did I miss something? (gist updated)

Comment: Set a debug statement just before the modal('show') and see if it gets called. You do that using this statement: debugger; Reload your app with that statement and dev tool open. Or, let me debug your app remotely

Comment: Okay, I found two things that are going on: each time I parse everything the number of function calls increment by one. Second thing is that after first loop every time modal shows up it automatically dismisses itself (how come?). 

Oh, and no error logs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101096/discussion-between-prashant-palikhe-and-jean-darme).